# Creating functions in R with iterative code

Tags: r, for-loop, while-loop, apply

I work with surveys and would like to export a large number of tables (drawn from data frames) into an .xlsx or .csv file. I use the `xlsx` package to do this. This package requires me to stipulate which column in the excel file is the first column of the table. Because I want to paste multiple tables into the .csv file I need to be able to stipulate that the first column for table n is the length of table (n-1) + x number of spaces. To do this I planned on creating values like the following.

dt# is made by changing a table into a data frame.

```
table1 <- table(df$y, df$x)
dt1 <- as.data.frame.matrix(table1)
```

Here I make the values for the number of the starting column

```
startcol1 = 1
startcol2 = NCOL(dt1) + 3
startcol3 = NCOL(dt2) + startcol2 + 3
startcol4 = NCOL(dt3) + 3 + startcol2 + startcol3
```

And so on. I will probably need to produce somewhere between 50-100 tables. Is there a way in R to make this an iterative process so I can create the 50 values of starting columns without having to write 50+ lines of code with each one building on the previous?

I found stuff on stack overflow and other blogs about writing for - loops or using apply type functions in R but this all seemed to deal with manipulating a vector as opposed to adding values to the workspace. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use a structure similar to this:

Your list of files to read:

```
file_list = list.files("~/test/",pattern="*csv",full.names=TRUE)
```

for each file, read and process the data frame and capture how many columns there are in the frame you are reading/processing:

```
columnsInEachFile = sapply(file_list,
       function(x)
       {
         df = read.csv(x,...) # with your approriate arguments
         # do any necessary processing you require per file
         return(ncol(df))
       }
)
```

The cumulative sum of the number of columns plus 1 will indicate the start columns of a data frame that contains your processed data stuck next to each other:

```
columnsToStartDataFrames = cumsum(columnsInEachFile)+1
columnsToStartDataFrames = columnsToStartDataFrames[-length(columnsToStartDataFrames)] # last value is not the start of a data frame but the end
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `tab.lst` is a list containing tables, then you can do:

```
cumsum(c(1, sapply(tail(tab.lst, -1), ncol)))
```

Basically, what I'm doing here is I'm looping through all the tables but the last one (since that one's start col is determined by the second to last), and getting each table's width with `ncol`.  Then I'm doing the cumulative sum over that vector to get all the start positions.

And here is how I created the tables (tables based on all possible combinations of columns in `df`):

```
df <- replicate(5, sample(1:10), simplify=F)     # data frame with 5 columns
names(df) <- tail(letters, 5)                    # name the cols
name.combs <- combn(names(df), 2)                # get all 2 col combinations
tab.lst <- lapply(                               # make tables for each 2 col combination 
  split(name.combs, col(name.combs)),            #   loop through every column in name.combs
  function(x) table(df[[x[[1]]]], df[[x[[2]]]])  #   ... and make a table
)
```